# link featured image to external link

Tags: custom-post-types, images, metabox, post-thumbnails, urls

I made custom post type "Collections" and  I populate every post through featured image. Now I need to link every featured image to appropriate external link.  So far I managed to add meta box to media uploader with this piece of code in `functions.php`:

```
    function be_attachment_field_credit( $form_fields, $post ) {


    $form_fields['be-url'] = array(
        'label' => 'URL',
        'input' => 'text',
        'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'be_url', true ),
        'helps' => 'Add URL',
    );

    return $form_fields;
}

add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'be_attachment_field_credit', 10, 2 );



function be_attachment_field_credit_save( $post, $attachment ) {


    if( isset( $attachment['be-url'] ) )
update_post_meta( $post['ID'], 'be_url', esc_url( $attachment['be-url'] ) );

    return $post;
}

add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_save', 'be_attachment_field_credit_save', 10, 2 );
```

And then in my single.php I add

```
echo get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'be_url', true);
```

Now, when I click on featured image in admin panel in order to populate the meta box with url (for example http://www.google.com), the metabox saves the link, but when I go to my page where my featured image is, the featured image is not linked at all. How do i make my featured image go to external link? Thanx.

Comment: Could you add the code in your template that is supposed to show the link?

Comment: Sure, sorry, I just did. Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like you are storing the url as a meta value of the post, while you are trying to retrieve it as a meta value of the post attachment.

Comment: Sorry to be very persistant, but I am a newbie and do not know how to resolve this myself. Can you show me the right code that will do what I want? I m lost.

Answer (score 1):

In WordPress attachments are treated as posts, with their own titles, excerpts and metavalues. So if a post has an attachment there are two sets of metavalues, one for the post itself and one for the attachment.

You are using `update_post_meta( $post['ID'] ...` to store the url. So it is stored as a metavalue of the post.

You are retrieving with `get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id() ...`, so you are looking for a metavalue of the attachment. To retrieve it you must not use `get_post_thumbnail_id()` but `$post['ID']`, because that's where you stored that url.